# How do I do before yesterday query on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

Here's my dataset

```
No. timestamp                    letter
1   2018-07-07 00:15:52          A
2   2018-07-07 09:55:34          A
3   2018-07-07 14:13:32          A
4   2018-07-08 02:22:51          A
5   2018-07-08 13:15:52          A
6   2018-07-08 18:52:43          A
7   2018-07-09 01:05:52          A
8   2018-07-09 09:15:52          A
```

I want to drop the last 24 hours lates timestamp in this data, which is anything `2018-07-08 09:15:52` (24 hours before latest timestamp), so the question is

```
No. timestamp                    letter
1   2018-07-07 00:15:52          A
2   2018-07-07 09:55:34          A
3   2018-07-07 14:13:32          A
4   2018-07-08 02:22:51          A
```

How suppose I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with subtract 1 day from last/max datetime:

```
df = df[df['timestamp'] < df['timestamp'].iloc[-1] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')]
```

Or:

```
df = df[df['timestamp'] < df['timestamp'].max() - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')]
```

---

```
print (df)
   No.           timestamp letter
0    1 2018-07-07 00:15:52      A
1    2 2018-07-07 09:55:34      A
2    3 2018-07-07 14:13:32      A
3    4 2018-07-08 02:22:51      A
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.DateOffset` to subtract a day from the maximum date. Then use a Boolean mask.

```
# convert to datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# calculate max date permitted
max_date = df['timestamp'].max() - pd.DateOffset(days=1)

print(max_date)

2018-07-08 09:15:52

# apply Boolean mask
res = df[df['timestamp'] < max_date]

print(res)

   No.           timestamp letter
0    1 2018-07-07 00:15:52      A
1    2 2018-07-07 09:55:34      A
2    3 2018-07-07 14:13:32      A
3    4 2018-07-08 02:22:51      A
```